ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed
I'm performing integration tests on my API which includes the following technologies:
Node.js, Express, Jest, and Sequelize.
The problem is that when running tests, I'm encountering the following error in my database:
"Sequelize ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!
And this happens randomly in some integration tests for the "user" feature of my API.
I've tried changing the connection pool, swapping values, testing other ways to create or update user data in the repository, but I always get this error. The failing tests are random; sometimes they work, and sometimes they don't, but the error is always the same—the repository functions with Sequelize that return this error. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here's my code
user model
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
  }
  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    full_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    is_active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true,
    },
  }, 
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false,
    hooks: {
      afterCreate: (record) => {
        delete record.dataValues.password;
        delete record.dataValues.is_active;
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};

user repository with functions and methods like
async delete (id) {
        try {
            const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
            await User.update(
                { is_active: false },
                {
                    where: {id: id},
                    transaction: t
                }
            );
            await t.commit();
        } catch (error) {
            await t.rollback();
            throw new ApiError(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,'Error while deleting user');
        }
    };

integration test:
const httpStatus = require('../../src/utils/statusCodes');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../app');
const db = require('../../src/database/models');
const User = db.user;
const Token = db.token;

describe('Testing user feature', () => {
  let tempUser;
  let token;
  beforeAll(async () => {     
    tempUser = await User.create({
      id: 100000,
      full_name: 'Porra',
      email: 'porra@gmail.com',
      password: '$2b$10$OMDQ.q5dkZAZkQH1g5W6IOP4ZLCwBV4xnTCHDng2pNhlWOpq/n5xO',
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date(),
      is_active: true
    }); 
    const loginResponse = await request(app).post('/login').send({"email": tempUser.email, "password": "1234"});
    token = loginResponse.body.token;
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await Token.destroy({ where: { user_id: tempUser.id } });
    await User.destroy({ where: { id: tempUser.id } });
    await db.sequelize.close();  
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    await db.sequelize.closeConnections();
  });

  it('Should update a user', async () => {
    const updatedUser = await request(app).put(`/users/${tempUser.id}`).set('Authorization', token).send({
      full_name: 'Tadeuzinho Smith'
    });
    expect(updatedUser.status).toBe(httpStatus.OK);
    expect(updatedUser.body.details).toBe('User updated successfully');
  });
  it('Should delete a user', async () => {
    const deletedUser = await request(app).delete(`/users/${tempUser.id}`).set('Authorization', token);
    expect(deletedUser.status).toBe(200);
    expect(deletedUser.body.details).toBe('User deleted successfully');
  });
});

PS: the issue only occurs when I run the integration test. If I do it via Postman, everything runs normally.
And using the debugger, I can confirm that the error always happens when Sequelize tries to perform an update or delete through these tests in the repository.
